# Custom checkbox not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to make a custom checkbox such that I can retrieve the value in Flask, but for some reason it is not coming through.

Here is my HTML/CSS/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .checkbox {
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid black;
        cursor: default;
      }
      .checkbox p {
        display: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 14px;
        max-height: 14px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        color: #777;
      }
      .checkbox.selected p {
        display: block;
      }
      input[type="checkbox"].hiddencheckbox {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="{{ url_for("load_checkbox") }}" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox" onclick="toggleCheck(this)">
      <p>&check;</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="morning" class="hiddencheckbox">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleCheck(checkbox) {
      var realcheckbox = checkbox.childNodes[1];
      checkbox.classList.toggle("selected");
      realcheckbox.checked ^= 1;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

And my Python:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def load_checkbox():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.form)
    return render_template("checkbox.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is what it prints when I click submit, regardless of the state of the checkbox: `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

I would like it to print `ImmutableMultiDict([('morning', 'on')])` (or similar) if the checkbox is checked, and `ImmutableMultiDict([('morning', 'off')])` (or similar) or `ImmutableMultiDict([])` if the checkbox is not checked.

What am I missing here? Why is it not working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is `checkbox.childNodes[3]` for some reason... Well now it works.